# What is an old question for the purpose of the Werewolf Hunter hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

[It says](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/):

> Edit 5 old questions on meta.

What is the definition of an old question?

Comment: A question that isn't new! 

Comment: Please don't make this a reason to go on a bad edit spree, such as swapping upvote with up-vote or British with American spelling

Comment: I'm disappointed in your latest edits on Meta. The revisions were poor and unnecessary, and had to be reverted by other users.

Comment: خوش بطه تلعب شناو

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just [click on the hat](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/werewolf-hunter):

> edited 5 questions on meta that were posted more than a year ago

Comment: I'll go the question one better: WHICH Meta? Any Meta'

Comment: No, the meta associated to the site. Doing this on Meta Stack Overflow gives you the hat on Stack Overflow. Doing it on Meta Super User gives you the hat on Super User.